# Vertx 3.6.3: eventBus.send() with DeliveryOptions fail

Tags: vert.x, vertx-eventbus

my Groovy code:

```
class GatewayVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  DeliveryOptions HOP_OPTS = new DeliveryOptions( sendTimeout:5000 )
  // also tried
  //DeliveryOptions HOP_OPTS = new DeliveryOptions()
  //DeliveryOptions HOP_OPTS = new DeliveryOptions().setSendTimeout( 5000 )

  @Override
  void start() throws Exception {    
    vertx.eventBus().send( 'addr', [ aa:42 ], HOP_OPTS ){ println it }
  }
}
```

fails with

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No message codec for type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
>       at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.CodecManager.lookupCodec(CodecManager.java:101)
>       at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.clustered.ClusteredEventBus.createMessage(ClusteredEventBus.java:180)
>       at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.send(EventBusImpl.java:111)

If I ommit the setting `sendTimeout` it fails with the same exception.

The following line works just fine:

```
vertx.eventBus().send( 'gateway', [ aa:42 ] ){ doSomeStuff() }
```

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: I think we need to know a bit more about the issue. Can you provide a mini example showing the problem? It is hard to tell if you're using JavaScript or Groovy just from one line of code...

Comment: @PauloLopes yes, it's groovy. see the updated question with a minimal example

Comment: I believe the issue comes from the vertx API that in this specific case is using generics, so the second argument is seen as `Object`, for this reason groovy isn't doing any transformation to `JsonObject` and it fails. I think if you cast the second argument to `JsonObject` is should give the expected results.

Comment: @PauloLopes I will try that out and let you know

Comment: @PauloLopes indeed it worked with `vertx.eventBus().send( 'addr', new JsonObject( aa:42 ), HOP_OPTS )`. I think it's worth file a bug

Comment: @PauloLopes https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-lang-groovy/issues/75